Send message from bot to another bot telegram
Basically I want my bot to text another bot, I want to achieve this so that I can text bots like if I was a new user since my bots telegram Id is different, so far i see that's not possible, that telegram prevents bots from talking to each other.
Is there a way to text bot1 using bot2 and maybe get the replies of bot2 forwarded to a real user?
Tried doing it and I couldn't see the replies of the bot I was texting, I don't even know if my bot even texted the other bot, how can I even know?

It is not possible to send message from a bot to another bot,
But it is possible to send message to bot or contacts, etc by using user-bot.
This is not the regular type of telegram bots, actually it is the real user in Telegram that you can control it by Telegram API development tools.
For using user-bot you have to learn Telethon or Pyrogram libraries in python, also you need to get api-hash and api-id from Telegram API development tools.

api-hash and api-id are not the api-key that Bot-Father gives you.

